# glass shower door no studs

Tags: doors, shower

I am about to install my frameless shower door and realized I am missing the stud by two inches I have two layers of 1/2 cement board and have found some anchors that can hold 600lbs will this be enough support the door weighs about 80lbs

Comment: 600lbs but the continuous vibration of shutting the door is not the same as supporting a shelf etc

Comment: You'll probably be fine, but more details on the anchors (picture) would be good.  You could have totally the wrong thing and we wouldn't know.

Comment: https://www.homedepot.com/p/WingIts-Stud-Less-Install-Grab-Bar-Fastener-TB-WINGIT-RES/301294167

Comment: I decided I don't want to deal with any problems down the road so im ripping out the wall next to the shoer and will slide a couple 2x4's for support

Comment: Probably the safest bet to do it that way, write it up as an answer and accept it to close out the question.+